# How to define template selections depends on the parameter class has a typedef or not

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

What I need:

```
template <class Context/*if Context has a Buffer typedef*/>
struct Buffer {
    typedef typename Context::Buffer type;
};

template <class Context/*if Context doesn't have a Buffer typedef*/>
struct Buffer {
    typedef std::shared_ptr<void> type;
};
```

If the parameter class Context has a Buffer typedef, then it's used, otherwise shared_ptr would be used.

How to write the templates? thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you insist on C++11 or the tag is just there?

Comment: please please please let it be c++14. It's so much easier. Well... less to write.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is fairly straightforward using a `void_t` helper:

```
#include <memory>
#include <type_traits>


template <typename...> using void_t = void;

template <class Context,class = void>
struct Buffer {
    typedef std::shared_ptr<void> type;
};

template <class Context>
struct Buffer<Context,void_t<typename Context::Buffer> > {
    typedef typename Context::Buffer type;
};



int main()
{
    struct Context1 {
    };

    struct Context2 {
        typedef int Buffer;
    };

    {
        using A = Buffer<Context1>::type;
        using B = std::shared_ptr<void>;
        static_assert(std::is_same<A,B>::value,"");
    }
    {
        using A = Buffer<Context2>::type;
        using B = int;
        static_assert(std::is_same<A,B>::value,"");
    }
}
```

Note that `std::void_t` is in C++17, but it is easy enough to create your own.

Answer (score 1):

Use partial class template specializations with SFINAE. It works even with C++11.

[(Live example)](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0d3c8a9750345ce5)

```
struct A
{
    using tag = void;  
    static constexpr const char *name = "A";
};

struct B
{    
    static constexpr const char *name = "B";
};


template <typename T> struct S
{
    static void func()
    {
        std::cout << T::name << " - no tag\n";
    };
};

template <typename T, typename = typename T::tag> using enable_if_has_tag = T;

template <typename T> struct S<enable_if_has_tag<T>>
{
    static void func()
    {
        std::cout << T::name << " - has tag\n";
    };
};

int main()
{
    S<A>::func(); // -> `A - has tag`
    S<B>::func(); // -> `B - no tag`
}
```

Comment: @SunYi-Ming Compiler name and exact version please, as well as the error message. I wouldn't be surprised if MSVC isn't smart enough for this.

Comment: clang++, Apple LLVM version 8.1.0 (clang-802.0.42). clang++ -std=c++14 -Wall -g -o test test.cc.     error: class template partial specialization does not specialize any template argument; to define the primary template, remove the template argument list template <typename T> struct S<enable_if_has_tag<T>>

Comment: @SunYi-Ming Huh. Didn't expect clang to fail here.